# Meanings of some symbols in electronics

Tags: power-electronics

I am new to electronics and i want to get about what do the symbols encircled in red signify?
Can anyone tell me what is happening in the diagram. Please help me.
Regards

[image: vXt81].png

Comment: But Please do tell me what do the encircled symbols indicate?

Comment: It's not an electronic schematic. I would call it logical block diagram.

Answer (score 5):

It is a left shift operation. The first is a shift by 1 bit, the second is a shift by 2.

For example, let's consider an 8 bit word like the following (space added between each 4 bits for readability):

```
x: 1101 0011
<<------------ direction of the shift
```

if you shift it to the left by one bit, i.e. by one position, you get:

```
y: 1010 0110
<<------------ direction of the shift
```

Note that the leftmost bit has been "pushed out" of the word, whereas the rightmost bit has been replaced by a 0 (i.e. a 0 has been "pushed in from the right").

Shifting by two bits is equivalent to two consecutive 1 bit shifts, therefore if you shift y by one bit you get:

```
z: 0100 1100
```

Hence z is the result of left-shifting y by 1 bit or, equivalently, left-shifting x by 2 bits.

Comment: Thanx for your reply :)

Comment: Can you please tell me why upper table is shifted by one and lower table is not shifted at all. And why later twice shifting is done?

Comment: @aman2392 this is a whole different question from the one you posted. You should post another question.

Answer (score 4):

In many programming languages the `<<` operator is used symbolise a bit-shift to the left. Similarly `>>` is a bit shift to the right. See wikipedia on [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts)

In binary arithmatic, shift operations are equivelent to multiplication by a power of two (in the same way as in decimal arithmatic adding an extra digit, like 10 -> 100, if multiplication by a power of ten. Therefore the first  shift operation is a equivelent to a multiplication by two and the second (marked as a scaling accumulator) is a multiplication by four. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-using-only-bit-shifting-and-adding) for more binary multipication by shifting examples.